# File Upload into the Application folder - Zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

i want to upload a file from the form into my Application folder(public/img/clientes/).
my form file upload field:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'foto',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'file',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Logo da empresa:',
        ),
    ));
```

my add action function on the controller:

```
public function addAction()
{

    $form = new ClienteForm();


    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {


        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();

        $form->setData($data);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            $name = $data['foto'];
            if(isset($name)){
                if(!empty($name)){
                    $location = __DIR__."../../../public/img/clientes/";
                    if(!move_uploaded_file($name, $location)){
                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->clienteManager->addNewCliente($data);

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('clientes');
        }
    }
    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => $form
    ]);
}
```

I cant seam to find the reason for this not to work
If anyone could help me with a solution here i would be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope everything is self-descriptive here. Just the upload location is a bit strange. As every request is handled through `index.php` by ZF and this file uses `chdir(dirname(__DIR__))` method to go to upper level, so everything is relative to the **application root**. That's why we can access directly `public/img/clientes`, in this case. But the recommendation set it via the configuration in `module.config.php`. And make it available using ServiceManager.

Make sure your **upload directory** has a right permission.

```
...

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

    // Merge data thus
    $data = array_merge_recursive(
        $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
        $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
    );

    $form->setData($data);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        // Upload path
        $location = "public/img/clientes/";

        // A bit validation of uploaded file
        $allowedExtension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        $extension = explode('.', $data['foto']['name']);
        $extension = end($extension);
        $fileName = time() . '.' . $extension;

        // Check if everything is OK!
        if (0 === $data['foto']['error'] && in_array($extension, $allowedExtension)) {
            move_uploaded_file($data['foto']['tmp_name'], $location . $fileName);
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong!';
        }
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this well described answer!  Its working now.